# Dell Optiplex GX280 with no OS installed does not recognize keyboard, needs BIOS update

Tags: hard-drive, keyboard, bios

I am wondering how to upgrade the bios version in this machine, bios does not recognize my keyboard which has the PS1/PS2 plug on it. Usb adapter used but machine is not recognizing. Checked the bios on the hard drive and I need a newer version for machine to recognize my keyboard. Help

Comment: Did you try another keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Dell support website](http://support.dell.com), go to Drivers and Downloads, enter the service tag of your system (should be 7 alphanumeric characters on a small sticker on the back or top of your system), and you'll be presented with a list of drivers and BIOS updates for your system.

The BIOS updater runs from Windows.  You can run it from a WinPE boot CD/USB drive or possibly a BartPE boot CD/USB drive, which you will have to either [make](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665%28WS.10%29.aspx) on another working computer, or obtain from someone else.